# is it possible open links in new page-window?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I use The List Category Post plugin and i'm very satisfied, but if i would make open the posts (list post) in another page not in the same.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you add some explanation with link to the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was implemented for version 0.36 with the `link_target` attribute:

**link_target** - Select the `target` attribute for links to posts (target=_blank, _self, _parent, _top, *framename*).

Example: `[catlink id=3 link_target=_blank]` will create:

`<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=45" title="Test post" target="_blank">Test post</a>`

Stay tuned for version 0.36 to update.

Comment: yes - this is the answer.

Comment: @Bibi mark this answer as correct if you think it's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/?

You can use jquery to make all the .lcp_catlist links open in a new window - add this code to your footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('.lcp_catlist li a').prop('target', '_blank');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct plugin.
Thanks for yours answers. I don't thing I'am capable to use jquery :)